# Unity bar and top panel bar have disappeared

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Ubuntu Version 11.10: My Unity bar and top panel have disappeared. All other features are running, it has happened only for one Login. My 2 year old who fiddled with the system seems to have given it more than it can handle...

Answer (score 0):

You can try `unity --reset` from a terminal. The manual says:

```
--reset
          This option allows the user to reset profile parameters in  com‐
          piz and restart the Unity shell with default settings.
```

It should restore unity settings to the original.